# Недокошенный / не докошенный мною луг

Tags: орфография

Мы все знаем, что, если причастие имеет зависимое слово, оно пишется с *не* по-отдельному: *Не кошенный позавчера луг.* Однако есть же приставка *недо-*! Как правильно?

`Недокошенный мною луг был полон сорняков.`

`Не докошенный мною луг был полон сорняков.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Недокошенный" -- это прилагательное, обозначающее такое свойство, как недокошенность. Это единое слово, и оно пишется слитно:

- Недокошенный мною луг был полон сорняков.

Раздельное написание необходимо, когда "не" относится к докошенному лугу:

- Это не докошенный луг мною луг, а пустошь, где и косить было нечего.